# Why does pair production have a minimum energy?

Tags: photons, pair-production

This was an exam question I recently encountered, and it sparked my interest.

To me, the following makes sense:

Given that pair production has no maximum energy (since $E_{min} \geq 2E_o$), the minimum energy is the *only energy theshold* for pair production to occur. With this in mind, had there been no threshold, pair production could occur at any time, irrespective of the energy of the photon causing it.

The question is quite simply, has something gone over my head? Or is my train of thought along the right lines?

Comment: Hi Joshua. What are you actually asking. Why there is a minimum energy theshold? If so that's just conservation of energy.

Comment: Not quite, I think put more simply the question is asking "why is the minimum energy of pair production what it is?"

Comment: I'm afraid it still isn't clear. The minimum obviously has to be at least twice the rest energy of the two particles created otherwise energy wouldn't be conserved. Are you asking whether it can be equal to this energy or whether it has to be greater than this energy by some amount?

Comment: Would it make more sense if I asked what would be the consequences if this threshold didn't exist? i.e. If any amount of energy would suffice?

Comment: Then energy wouldn't be conserved. For example you can't make an electron positron pair, with a total mass of 1022 keV from a photon with an energy less than 1022 keV because the extra energy would have to appear from nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photon must have a minimum energy because otherwise energy will not be conserved. Also, the photon must be near a nucleus because linear momentum also has to be conserved. The decay will happen only if these two conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Are there applications or real-life examples of pair production?

Comment: It's an effect that happens when a (sufficiently) high-energy photon enters a (detector) material. It is one of the processes (along with the photoelectric and compton effect) that contribute to the energy detection of the incident photon. The inverse process (electron-positron annihilation into two gammas) can also happen and has some important applications (e.g. PET scan).